# Efficient way to associate each row to latest previous row with condition.(PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, optimization, subquery

I have a table in which two different kind of rows are inserted:

- Some rows represent a datapoint, a key-value pair in a specific of time
- Other rows represent a new status, which persist in the future until the next status

In the real problem, I have a timestamp column which stores the order of the events. In the SQL Fiddle example I am using a SERIAL integer field, but it is the same idea.

Here is the example:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a0823/6

I am looking for an **efficent** way to retrieve each row of the first type with the its status (which is given by the latest status row before current row) associated.

The query on the sqlfiddle link is an example, but uses two subqueries which is very inefficient.

I cannot change the structure of the table nor create other tables, but I can create any necessary index on the table.

I am using PostgreSQL 11.4

Comment: If they are different things: maybe put them into separate tables?

Comment: @wildplasser I explicitly said in the question thatI cannot create other tables.

Comment: If you want it to be **efficient**: modelling your data is step zero.

Comment: @wildplasser That is clear, but in the real world there are sometimes non-technical restrictions that makes that impossible. Which is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method is probably to use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             max(attrvalue) filter (where attrname = 'status_t1') over (partition by grp_1 order by id) as status_t1,
             max(attrvalue) filter (where attrname = 'status_t2') over (partition by grp_2 order by id) as status_t2
      from (select p.*,
                   count(*) filter (where attrname = 'status_t1') over (order by id) as grp_1,
                   count(*) filter (where attrname = 'status_t2') over (order by id) as grp_2
            from people p
           ) p
     ) p
where attrname not in ('status_t1', 'status_t2');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b8c7dba48b6e474ec1317f908b5eb06) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any documentation about the use of 'filter' in window funciton in Postgresql?

Comment: @JoséD. . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I learned a new technique. In this specific problem, however, I ended up with a more efficient solution by using subqueries and a partial index on rows with attrname = 'status_t%'